# vertically justified flexbox elements

Tags: css, flexbox

The old `display:box` had the ability to justify element vertically, so for **N** number of elements with **H** defined height, they will arrange themselves justified (*vertically*) in relation to the parent element.

Is there any way of achieving this using the current `dislpay:flex` system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the flex rule `justify-content: space-between;`. Put that on your parent element and it will align the items so the first one touches the start of the container, the last one touches the end of the container, and the rest of the space is distributed between the elements.

You can also use `align-items` to align your elements in the direction perpendicular to your flex direction. For example if your `flex-direction` is `column` (vertical), then `justify-content` will justify items vertically and `align-items` will align them horizontally. Conversely if your `flex-direction` is `row` (horizontal), then `justify-content` will justify items horizontally and `align-items` will align them vertically.

More info here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

With `display: flex` you have `justify-content` for horizontal alignment and `align-items` for vertical alignment.